# Create or update XML elements by XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need a little help.
I have an XML like this:

```
<params>
    <param>
        <name>Q1</name>
        <value>A1</value>
    </param>
    <param>
        <name>Q99</name>
        <value>A99</value>
    </param>
    <param>
        <name>Q55</name>
        <value>A55</value>
    </param>
</params>
```

And I need XSLT to find if I have a **param** with **name** equal to 'Q33'. If it exists, it's **value** should be updated to 'A33_new', if it doesn't exist, next should be added:

```
<param>
    <name>Q33</name>
    <value>A33_new</value>
</param>
```

Comment: Please show us the XSLT you've tried so far, we can't help you debug your code unless we can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use the identify transformation to copy over everything**

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

**except squelch `Q33` parameters**

```
  <xsl:template match="param[name='Q33']"/>
```

**and add the new `Q33` parameter (really whether it existed in the input or not, per your stated requirement):**

```
  <xsl:template match="params">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <param>
        <name>Q33</name>
        <value>A33_new</value>
      </param>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Altogether:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="param[name='Q33']"/>

  <xsl:template match="params">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <param>
        <name>Q33</name>
        <value>A33_new</value>
      </param>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, this works.
But if I have to add more than one param, then only the last template works.